# How is typecasting and dereferencing works here

Tags: c

I am typecasting the address of a character variable whose address 0x7ffc684486ef to an integer pointer. The value at the address 0x7ffc684486ef is 16, when I dereference using the integer pointer it would read 4 bytes starting from address 0x7ffc684486ef, but it return value 0, how is it. Is my understanding wrong ?.

```c
int main()
{   
    char var;
    int *ptr;
    
    ptr = (int *)&var;
    printf("%p %p\n", &var, ptr);
    *ptr = 16;
    printf("%d %d\n", var, *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

O/P

```
0x7ffc684486ef 0x7ffc684486ef
16 0
```

2. Why the below code does not print anything.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define ADDRESS 0x7ffc684486ef

typedef struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
}Point;

int main()
{
    
    Point *var  = (Point *)(ADDRESS);
    var->x = 2;
    var->y = 5;
    printf("Location: %p\n", var);
    printf("Values: %d %d\n", var->x, var->y); 
}
```

O/P:

```
NIL
```

Comment: Do you expect the address `0x7ffc684486ef` to point to memory that you can write to? An address in one program has no meaning in another program.

Comment: `ptr = (int *)&var` followed by `*ptr = 16` leads to *undefined behavior*. Also, addresses aren't fixed, you can't hard-code addresses and pointers in a normal system with virtual memory.

Comment: Besides what they told you, in the first example you cast a pointer to int the address of a variable char (1 byte) and when a *p assigns 16 you put an integer (because p is int *) in the memory area of 1 byte but the size of an int is certainly greater than 1 byte (sizeof (int)). Your program will crash.

Comment: @dmaxime, Value 16 can be fit in 1 byte.

Comment: @Paul: No. Not with a int pointer. You can put 16 into a char with "char num = 16" but if you writte "char num; int *p = (int *)num; *p = 16" you are putting sizeof(int) bytes into sizeof(char) bytes.

Answer (score 1):

C allows wildly unsafe pointer conversion such as `ptr = (int *)&var;` without protesting. So it's likely that you get the same address even after changing the pointer type.

*However*, when you de-reference the `*ptr = 16;` you invoke an impressive number of undefined behavior bugs: out of bounds access, possible misaligned access, strict aliasing violation, accessing memory you don't have access to, and so on. *Don't do this*, this code is incredibly broken and there's no telling what the result might be. [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

The second example is even worse:

- How do you know there is memory you have access to at that address?
- It's a misaligned address so you can't access it as a struct on most computers
- The access of memory areas unknown by the compiler, such as hardware registers, has to be `volatile` qualified.

So it would seem that you make a misaligned address somewhere out in la-la-land and this too is wildly undefined behavior. There's no point in reasoning about any behavior you might encounter. Any form of behavior can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the concept related to *p = 16 ...
Look at this piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int numa = -1, num, numb = -1;
    int *p = (int *)&num;

    *p = 16;
    printf("\n%d %d %d %d", *p, numa, num, numb);
}
```

When it runs it will output:

```
16 -1 16 -1
```

Now try changing the data type to char on the line that declares 'num':

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char numa = -1, num, numb = -1;
    int *p = (int *)&num;

    *p = 16;
    printf("\n%d %d %d %d", *p, numa, num, numb);
}
```

you will receive "Segmentation fault".